# horizontally scrolling calendar

Tags: jquery, animation, calendar, horizontal-scrolling

I've used the following script
http://valums.com/scroll-menu-jquery/
to build a horizontally scrolling calender.

Here is how I've implemented it.

http://zifimusic.com/testing/horizontalCalendar.html

90% of the calendar activity I am expecting is within a month or two of the current date. However, I think I need to provide the ability to select any month. 
I was going to use the jQuery datepicker, but thought that this format allowed the user to always see the currently selected date, and allow me to mark out weeks or days that need attention in a interesting yet fairly simple interface, which (when styled) should take up considerably less height than a proper calendar.

I'm sure I've seen calendars like this before, but I couldn't find a script for making one.

I have two issues with this calender.
1) The year scrolls off the page, so you can't see what year you are looking at. 
I've added this line

```
 var windowWidth=jQuery(window).width();
  div.mousemove(function(e){

    jQuery('li.year').each(function(){

    if(jQuery(this).offset().left>0 && jQuery(this).offset().left<windowWidth){
               jQuery('h1',this).scrollLeft(offset().left-windowWidth);
```

but it doesn't seem to be having the desired effect of having the year stay visible and somewhat line up within the scrolling of the dates.

2) the scrolling is kinda nasty. it jumps WAY to far at times, and I haven't been able to get a smoother animation. If you enter the scrolling area at the left, it takes a HUGE jump, because it is using the window offset as the definition of how far it should scroll.
I think it would be much better if it only animated when the user scrolled left/right, but I haven't been able to get that. I've tried limiting the distance that the scroll travels, but then i don't get the entire calendar.

Really what I'm looking for is what is the best way to enable scrolling on something like this.

I should say that the use of the calendar is really for selecting weeks, not individual days, which makes this format easier again, because I can visually alternate weeks to create visible groupings.

Comment: I saw a brief demo of Mint.com, and it appears they have a horizontally sliding calendar, and I know they use jquery. Unfortunately, being from canada, I couldn't login to the point where I could get a view of their calendar working :(, but I think that is what I'm looking for. 

Can anybody comment on that?

Comment: I'm interested in your calendar. The link you provided is not active anymore. Is there a way to see it ? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to give you some ideas without real code, since I logged only for second :)

1., you could store your data range in one or two variables, e.g. `var startYear = 2009;`, then hide years you drew with all those date (i hope you understand :D) add one absolute div to show current year, which you'll recalculate on each mousemove.

If you know, that there are three years on timeline and you know that offsetLeft (example) is in range (0; 1/3 of timeline div width), than you know, that year that user is looking upon is the lowest and can draw it with something like `$('year-in-view').html('<b>'+startYear+'</b>');`

2., you could store previous position (yet again :) ) in some variable and check if the X-axis difference is bigger than 100px (or 200px... your choice) and if yes (`abs(current.x-last.x) > 100`), animate the div differently, so user will understand that he moved through two years.

Hope it helps,
Adam

Comment: Thanks adam, I just rewrote the entire thing yesterday, and now it works more like a cycle plugin. As far as the year scrolling, I kinda got that going by doing $(visibleYear).offset.left-$vsibleYear.width and a bunch of other crazy math, but it started looking really ugly. I decided to just repeat the year. I did this last night, here's a link to what I ended up with (still working on the styling)
http://zifimusic.com/testing/horizontalCalendar.html

Comment: looks good now :) although, it confused me for a second, that why i scroll for whole year, until i realized it's a year drawn next to every month :)